# What is an appropiate machine learning algorithm for my problem?

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, pattern-recognition

I was having an idea for a software, which would make use of machine learning, and I started to code it. I got stuck at selecting the algorithm, since I'm not familiar with this field.

My use-case is:

For teaching, I'm collecting Wi-Fi data, and measure signal strength, like:

```
My network, 86%
Neighbours network, 34%
Other network, 23%
```

Then I assign 2 numbers to it, each between -1 and +1, so for example: `(-0.65, 0.43)`

For the evaluation part, I give similar samples:

```
My network, 68%
Neighbours network, 27%
Other network, 36%
```

Then expect the algorithm to return something like: `(-0.63, 0.41)`

I'm thinking it would be neural networks or pattern recognition, but these are really broad terms.
I was hoping someone could tell me which algorithm(s) would cope well with this problem.

Comment: I don't understand the question. How do you go from your 3 percentages to the two numbers between -1 and +1 ?

Comment: By teaching the algorithm.

Comment: So you want to predict ground coordinates as function of signal strengths? You could also predict room as function of signal strengths. That might be a little easier for a start. Walls etc. will reduce the signal in a non-linear fashion so a non-linear model would probably be best. Neural-nets with one input for each wifi plus one or two hidden layers and two outputs may work well. You may need 500 training samples.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is not a use case for machine learning. Since each data point has only one dimension you can just intelligibly pick a threshold. Density estimation (KDE, GMM, etc..) would help you determine how to do this correctly.

If you are using this as a simple example of a machine learning algorithm, then try logistic regression. It will project your data between 0 and 1, from which point you can scale it between -1 and 1.